# Which event captures every edit to a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, richtextbox

I need to update the formatting of a rich text box after any change is made to the text (for example when the user presses a key and inserts a character). How can I do this?

KeyDown occurs too early and would not account for holding a key down anyway, KeyUp occurs too late, and neither would account for a cut or paste with the mouse.

It would be even better to receive to get this event before the change even appears on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the TextChanged event to know whenever the text has changed

Comment: That does not always work, as if the same text is put into the box, it will not trigger.

Comment: Does this occur before the change appears on screen?

@Mac If the same text is put into the box, why would I even care? Unless you are saying it does not preserve the formatting.

Comment: @Matt - It was just something to look for, since i had a text box that would load the rest of my form depending on the text, and even if the text was edited, and the new text was the same, i still wanted it to reload the form.

Comment: Try the 'TextInput' event, I think this should trigger even when you input the same text again, though it's untested by myself.

Comment: One more problem: If I change the text in the event handler, there is an infinite loop. How can I get around that?

Comment: @TheOddler TextInput doesn't seem to be triggered by inputting text. I am not sure why. PreviewTextInput does work however. The other problem is it is not triggered by deleting text.

Comment: That's very weird, then I'm out of ideas. As for the infinite loop, the only thing I can think of it keeping a bool 'RecentlyChangedTextInEvent' or something. Though it's pretty obvious why this loop occurs, and I would suggest you rethink that piece of code. Doesn't seem like a good idea to change text in the "textChanged" event :P

Comment: @TheOddler basically what I want to do is reformat the text every time anything changes.

Comment: Hmm, then this might help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/234703/WPF-TextBox-with-PreviewTextChanged-event-for-filt Otherwise, try the bool-thingy I described, that should work too. If you want I can make some sample code, though I'm at my vacation job atm, so can't really do much :P